# ItextSharp not maintain column width in pdf with c#

Tags: c#, itext

What i am doing is i am creating one simple html from c# side and tried to convert it in pdf using itextSharp

Here is the sample code of this

```
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(new Rectangle(288f, 144f), 2, 2, 2, 2);
                pdfDoc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
                pdfDoc.Close();
                return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "CONTRACTREGISTER.pdf");
```

the issue is as below :

When i have checked my html in browser in print preview it is displayed perfectly as show in below image

[image: IMAGE 1]

now when i process this html with itextsharp it does not preserve my column width setting , please check below image of output of itext sharp

[image: IMAGE 2]

see the difference of columns width for both image

Answer (score 1):

you can use PdfPTable object and set fixed width float array for the columns' width, like this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
table.TotalWidth = 500f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
float[] widths = new float[] { 20f, 60f, 60f, 30f};
table.SetWidths(widths);
```

if this didn't do what you need and you need to set column width by percent, then you can use [PDFflow](https://go.pdfflow.io/lib-home) library and set the column width like this:

```
DocumentBuilder.New().AddSection().AddTable()
// add 4 columns to the table
                           .AddColumnPercent("", 10).ToTable()
                           .AddColumnPercent("", 50).ToTable()
                           .AddColumnPercent("", 20).ToTable()
                           .AddColumnPercent("", 20).ToTable()
// add the first row
                           .AddRow()
// add the first cell and make it span 4 rows
                               .AddCellToRow()
                               .AddCellToRow()
                               .AddCellToRow()
                               .AddCellToRow()
// generate the PDF document
                           .ToDocument().Build("Result.pdf");
```

the result will be this:

[image]